# Elementary prealgerbra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Problem 1

Given to find sum of 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 I can solve as 1+9+2+8+3+7+4+6+5 45

My question is how can I use associate or commutative property to justify the reordering as above to find the sum.

Associative property: a+b = b+a. Therefore the above can be written as

1+2+3+4+5+6+7+9+8. -- 1st iteration applying associative property

1+2+3+4+5+6+9+7+8 -- 2nd iteration applying associative property

..........

1+9+2+3+4+5+6+7+8 -- 7th iteration applying associative property

At the end of this, the first pair can be proved 1+9. Similarly we can pair remaining.

A) Is this how you justify the pairing

B) is associative property only for two numbers.

C) may be we take associative property and provide proof similar that associative property can be extended to any n terms. Therefore use that as basis to prove the above problem.

I am trying to teach my young child prealgebra and in the process I am learning myself. I have to justify to the child by using the associative and commutative properties, these pairings are justifiable.

Problem 2 Given problem (1+2+3+4+5)+(6+7+8+9). I can pair them up similar to above. These are in parentheses, I can use the associative or commutative properties by ignoring the parentheses or using numbers outside of parentheses A) is it justifiable to ignore the parentheses for all or few of the elements B) if yes then what proof exists to show that it is justifiable. If no then how do you use the properties to do the pairing.

Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: $a+b=b+a$ is generally called the commutative property, whereas $(a+b)+c=a+(b+c)$ is the associative property. Moreover, I don't understand what the first problem asks for. Do you just want to show that you can reorder the operations? And then calculate the easier sums $(1+9)+(2+8)+\ldots$?

Comment: I think children will understand these properties intuitively.

Comment: Agree with Ali. There is a risk of turning a nice idea (add up the numbers in a different order that makes the addition simpler) into mystery math.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, let's get our properties straight:

**commutative**: $a+b = b+a$

**associative**: $a+b+c = (a+b)+c = a+(b+c)$

So in rearranging the sum, you are iteratively applying the commutative, not associative property (in general, it is acceptable to rearrange these in a single step).  Once you have the numbers in the right order, you can justify the pairing via the associative property, stating:
$$
\begin{align}
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 &= \text{...by the commutative property} \\
1+9+2+8+3+7+4+6+5 &= \text{...by the associative property}\\
(1+9)+(2+8)+(3+7)+(4+6)+5 
\end{align}
$$
I'm not quite sure what you mean by the rest of it, so I'll stop here for now.